SVG needs to be 100vh but it excedes it in large and medium screens
Im creating a website,and i also created an SVG using adobe illustrator, for it to be the background or the whole image really to that website.
The thing is that, when emulating a phone or an ipad using chrome devtools, the svg size is correct, and it matches the viewport ( almost always or just by an inch )...
But when i start to up the window resolution, the SVG starts to resize and starts getting bigger and bigger, and my plan is to always match the VH of the screen for all of it to be visible always, responsively, even if its a higher resolution or lower.
To accomplish this i've used:
<body class="100vh">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
            <div class="card align-items-center">
               <img src="/Imagenes/back_3.svg" id="background-image" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

I tried of using a lot of css properties, and i've ended up using bootstrap classes because somehow thats how i got the best result out of this, it it's still no the desirable one.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

This is not an SVG problem, it's an image problem

If the SVG is used as a CSS background image you can control the size and position. In the example I use the following SVG:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="orange"/>
</svg>



body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgMTAwIj4KICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI1MCIgY3k9IjUwIiByPSI1MCIgZmlsbD0ib3JhbmdlIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}




FYI, no need for Base64 nowadays. CSS accepts SVG; the # hash-tag (in #123456 color and href/id references) needs to be escaped with %23
